# Sending payment to 2 receivers using PayPal SDK

Tags: android, paypal, payment

I am new to using Paypal into an Android app. For the purpose of my project the user will have to send payment to 2 receivers and I am now sure that the SDK supports that. I had a look at the API documentation and did not find any setter methods where I will be able to set the receiver's emails.

Comment: Hi Georgi. It looks like you acquired a good answer below, but forget to reply, vote or accept. While responding is not mandatory here, the community would collapse if nobody did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to apply for Adaptive Payments. Once you apply for Adaptive payments you will be given the credentials you need. After that you can setup two or more receivers. 
From the [PayPal Documentation on the Developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) here is information on Adaptive Payments:

> **Adaptive Payments** has operations that enable the sending and receiving
>   of payments involving two or more parties. Each Adaptive Payments API
>   transaction includes a sender and one or more receivers of the
>   payment. Each transaction also includes the application owner, called
>   the "API Caller," who is an invisible third party that provides the
>   transaction flow and is the entity that makes the API calls. In most
>   scenarios, payment transactions are initiated by the buyer (in a send
>   type of payment arrangement) or by the seller (in a pay type of
>   payment arrangement).

You will need to download the [Mobile Library SDK](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL) from GitHub.
Here is the link to [APPS 101](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/apps101/) it gives the instructions for applying for Adaptive Payments.
[Page 20 of the Android Mobile Payments Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_android.pdf) has all the details on Adaptive Payments.
 
Here is the general guide for [How to Accept Payments on Android](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/).